# Karma/Jasmin Test Promise error inside of regular function

Tags: promise, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

First my Setup. I try to test some of my Ionic Pages etc.
And I have a login page where I want to test the Login.

This is my Login method:

```
doLogin() {
    let authHelper = this.injector.get(AuthHelper);
    authHelper.sendSignInLink(this.email).then(()=> {
     window.localStorage.setItem("userMail", this.email);
     let loginToast = this.toast.create({
       message: "Link to email succesfully send. In order to finish the login, it is necessary to click the send link.",
       duration: 3000,
       position: "bottom",
     });
     loginToast.present();
    }).catch(() => {
  throw new EmailSignInLinkError("invalid Mail");
  });
}
```

As we can see the method sendSignInLink is returning a promise and if the promise is rejected it should throw a custom error.

For my unit test I mocked the authHelperClass to a very simple mock:

```
export class AuthHelperMock {

public auth(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(2);
    });
}

public sendSignInLink(email: String): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (email != undefined || email != "")
            resolve(1);
        else
            reject("Invalid email");
    });
 }
}
```

Now is the Problem that I try to check on this thrown error from my promise.

My it case is:

```
    it('should not do the login', () => {
      component.email = "";
      expect(() => {
        component.doLogin();
    }).toThrowError(EmailSignInLinkError)
```

I know that this will not work because the promise is async and the case will fail before it throws the error. But I don't find any suitable solution beside changing my doLogin to a promise as well.

How can I check on this Promise within a regular function?